# Make dynamically loaded images ease in and out using actionscript

Tags: actionscript

I have 4 buttons and 4 images when I click a button a different image appears.  I want the images to ease in and out after each button click.  I have tried the code below but can't seem to figure it out.

```
home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, homeClick);
function homeClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    backgroundimg.source = "images/bluebg.jpg";
    var bluebgTween:Tween = new Tween(backgroundimg, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 1, 0, 3, true);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If fading in then fading out, set the initial alpha of **backgroundimg** to 0.

```
backgroundimg.alpha = 0;
```

You can then fade in on the **CLICK** event.  Note that I've swapped the begin and finish values for the **Tween**.

Once the tween has finished, the **yoyo()** method can then be used to fade out again.

```
home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, homeClick);
function homeClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    backgroundimg.source = "images/bluebg.jpg";
    var bluebgTween:Tween = new Tween(backgroundimg, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 0, 1, 3, true);

    bluebgTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onFinish);

    function onFinish(te:TweenEvent):void {
        bluebgTween.yoyo();
        bluebgTween.removeEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onFinish);
    }
}
```

I used these sites as a reference for this:

- http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3tweenclass/
- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html